# Using Pandas to calculate the percentage of each index's values

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I get stuck in pandas when I have a DataFrame like this:

| Person | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| A | Banana |
| A | Banana |
| B | Apple |
| C | Banana |
| A | Apple |
| F | Banana |
| D | Banana |

I need to calculate the percentage of each person's different fruits, like A has 4 fruits, which will return 50% Apple and 50% Banana. D has 1 fruit, which will return 100% Banana.

Is there any method that I can achieve this result?

Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.value_counts`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) :

```
result = (
            (df.groupby('Person')['Fruit']
               .value_counts(normalize=True))
               .astype(float)
               .map("{:.2%}".format)
          )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(result)

Person  Fruit 
A       Apple      50.00%
        Banana     50.00%
B       Apple     100.00%
C       Banana    100.00%
D       Banana    100.00%
F       Banana    100.00%
Name: Fruit, dtype: object
```